# Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm

Tags: java, string

Is the solution for [Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm): Haystack: AAAAAAAAAA, Needle: AAA, which is: 3, correct?

Because, there are 8 instances of AAA in the haystack, however as far as I understand the knuth-morris-pratt algorithm will only find 3. Am I wrong in thinking this?

Can this problem be solved by finding out the borders for every suffix in the string?

The following is my implementation of the KMP algorithm:

```
public static int occurrenceOfSubstring(char[] target, char[] pattern) {
        int[] overlay = new int[pattern.length];
        overlay[0] = -1;
        overlay[1] = 0;

        int i = 0, j = 1;

        while (j + 1 < pattern.length) {
            if (pattern[i] == pattern[j]) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    overlay[j + 1] = 1;
                } else {
                    overlay[j + 1] = overlay[j] + 1;
                }
                i++;
                j++;
            } else if (pattern[j] == pattern[0]) {
                i = 0;
            } else {
                j++;
            }
        }

        int l = 0,count=0;

        for (int k = 0; k < target.length; k++) {
            if (target[k] == pattern[l]) {
                if (l == pattern.length - 1) {
                    l = 0;
                    count++;
                } else {
                    l++;
                }
            } else {
                l = overlay[l] == -1 ? 0 : overlay[l];
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: This question appears to be best suited for the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site as it asks for an algorithm implementation review.

Comment: @Slanec This question belongs here, it is a question about an algorithm.  OP did his homework, and instead of asking "How to implement KMP?" presents his results so far and asks if they are correct.  [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is for reviewing architecture or style.

Comment: @bolo surely algorithm questions belong on programmers.se? It depends what is really being asked...

Comment: From your wiki article :However, just prior to the end of the current partial match, we passed an "AB" which could be the beginning of a new match, so we must take this into consideration..

Answer (score 1):

KMP focuses on optimizing the search when a full match search fails but a partial match can be reused to restart the search further down the haystack than with a naive approach. However the case you present has no partial matches, it always finds the full word at each search iteration. So indeed I would expect KMP to return 3 matches for the case you proposed. Do note that this is an edge case and one might be tempted to modify the algorithm to take advantage of the contextual information of the haystack or word or both but you are now going beyond KMP. Hope this helps.