# Why can I not solve the Longest increasing subsequence by simply sorting the sequence?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence#Efficient_algorithms says that the most efficient solution is in O(n log n), hence if I sort the sequence, it will be O(n log n) and then if I iterate through the sorted sequence, rejecting each item that is not increasing, it will be O(n), hence the algorithm would be in O(n log n + n) which is ~ O(n log n)...

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: *iterate through the sorted sequence, rejecting each item that is not increasing* - Read it again. That would be complete sequence. You've already sorted it. And that is not really what that algorithm is about.

Comment: Longest increasing subsequence of [2, 3, 1] is not the same thing as of [1, 2, 3].

Comment: @Jatin: "Why can I not solve the Longest increasing subsequence by simply sorting the sequence?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting the sequence would change the order of items in the original sequence, and your approach would always return a shortest sequence of the same length as the original total sequence.  Se Mehrdad's comment.

From your link:

In the binary Van der Corput sequence

0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15, …

a longest increasing subsequence is

0, 2, 6, 9, 13, 15.

Now let's apply your algorithim:

Sorted the original sequence becomes:

0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15

The longest increasing subsequnce here is:

0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15

Comment: Thank you very much for answering this really silly thought I had.. I should have tested it with the results on wiki.. forgive my naiveness.. However, can you please have a look at: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435497/knuthmorrispratt-algorithm?noredirect=1#comment32342555_21435497

Comment: No reason to apologize.  It's always easy to see the flaws in our assumptions after somone points them out.  I have this happen to me alllll the time.

Comment: Also I'll look at that question this evening.  I'm at work and don't have time to really look at that one right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you sort it then you destroy the input, and are no solving the real problem.

Answer (score -1):

"if I sort the sequence" 
Why do this? What is going to happen with all subsequences when you sort it? ;-)

Comment: This isn't really an answer.

Comment: Yes, should have been a comment